# Delphi - idFTP get current Directory

Tags: delphi, ftp, directory

I like to get the current Dir I am into on my FTP Server.
I know that I can switch the Dir with `idFtp1.ChangeDir('MyDirectory);` 
but how can I check if I am already into this Dir?

Comment: Are you supposed to be some kind of imposter? :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `TIdFTP.RetrieveCurrentDir`, which returns a string representing the name of the present working directory (current directory) on the server:

```
  ServerDir := IdFtp1.RetrieveCurrentDir;
  // Do whatever with ServerDir to see if you need to change to a different one
```